# python board game error will not reach threshold

Tags: python-3.x

i am making a simple board game for 2 players where you roll 2 dies and move thant many squares the first to 49 wins (see image at end)

however my program will not stop when that player reaches 49 or more

```
from random import randint
print("Welcome to my game please input the players names")
player1=input("Please enter player 1's name followed by the return key : ")
player2=input("Please enter player 2's name followed by the return key : ")
print("right then ", player1," and ",player2, " the game is simple i'll explain the rules as we go along")
player1position=1
player2position=1
while player1position or player2position <49:
    print("Its" , player1 , "' go ")
    dice1=randint(0,6)
    dice2=randint(0,6)
    print("Your first dice was a ", dice1, " and your second was a ", dice2)
    print("your total is ", dice1+dice2)
    player1position=player1position+dice1+dice2
    print("player one is now on square ", player1position)
    print("Its" , player2 , "' go ")
    dice1=randint(0,6)
    dice2=randint(0,6)
    print("Your first dice was a ", dice1, " and your second was a ", dice2)
    print("your total is ", dice1+dice2)
    player2position=player2position+dice1+dice2
    print("player two is now on square ", player2position)
else:
    if player1position > 49:
        print(player1 , "has won well done")
    else:
        print(player2 , "has won well done")
```

[board i am trying to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egmId.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, while dont need else clause. Then, the mistake you did was in the while clause. You want to check if your player1position is less than 49 and the same for your player2position, but if you check like that:

```
 while player1position or player2position <49:
```

You are checking, while var1 exists or var2 is less than 49... 
So It will be an infinite loop.

So, here is the code:

```
from random import randint
print("Welcome to my game please input the players names")
player1=input("Please enter player 1's name followed by the return key : ")
player2=input("Please enter player 2's name followed by the return key : ")
print("right then ", player1," and ",player2, " the game is simple i'll explain the rules as we go along")
player1position=1
player2position=1

while player1position<49 or player2position<49:
    print("Its" , player1 , "' go ")
    dice1=randint(0,6)
    dice2=randint(0,6)
    print("Your first dice was a ", dice1, " and your second was a ", dice2)
    print("your total is ", dice1+dice2)
    player1position=player1position+dice1+dice2
    print("player one is now on square ", player1position)
    print("Its" , player2 , "' go ")
    dice1=randint(0,6)
    dice2=randint(0,6)
    print("Your first dice was a ", dice1, " and your second was a ", dice2)
    print("your total is ", dice1+dice2)
    player2position=player2position+dice1+dice2
    print("player two is now on square ", player2position)

if player1position > player2position:
    print(player1 , "has won well done")
else:
    print(player2 , "has won well done")
```

A little fix:
It could be the case that player1position and player2position would be more than 49, we should check it with the last condition.